# How to produce a binary column in R from an existing numerical column?

Tags: r

Here are some sample data:

```
Age       Parent
0             4
2             4
5             3
8             3
10            4
15            2
18            2
19            0
```

The data represent male and female parental attendance at a bird nest. Here, 4= both parents are present, 3= only male is present, 2= only female is present, 0= neither parent present.

I would like to produce a new column (preferably in addition to the original parent column rather than replacing it) giving binary data, where 3 and 4 become '1' and 2 and 0 become '0'.

So my sample data would give the following binary column:

```
Age   Parent
0             1
2             1
5             1
8             1
10            1
15            0
18            0
19            0
```

I hope I have given enough information but please ask if you need some extra details.

Comment: `+(c(4,4,3,3,4,2,2,0) >= 3)` ?

Comment: `df$New_Parent <- df$Parent > 2` or `df$New_Parent <- +(df$Parent > 2)`.  The former will give you a boolean (true/false) column, the latter will give you the `1`/`0` that you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is the case with most R questions, there are a couple of different ways to do this, but the easiest is probably (let's say you've stored your data in a data frame `d`):

```
d$Father <- ifelse(d$Parent >= 3, 1, 0)
```

There are, of course, any number of logical vectors that could take the place of `d$Parent >= 3` in the above code.

You can also directly take advantage of the fact that R treats `1` and `TRUE` equivalently:

```
d$Dad <- d$Parent %in% c(3,4)
d$Dad_Num <- as.numeric(d$Dad <- d$Parent %in% c(3,4))
```

Both of those resulting vectors will work for most R applications.

For more complicated case handling, the `memisc` package provides a `cases` function (though the syntax takes a bit of getting used to):

```
library(memisc)
d$Father <- cases(
  d$Parent == 4 -> 1,
  d$Parent == 3 -> 1,
  d$Parent == 2 -> 0,
  d$Parent == 0 -> 0
)
```

This is overkill in your case, but may prove useful to know about in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
df$parentNew <- ifelse(df$Parent %in% c(3, 4), 1, 0)
df
  Age Parent parentNew
1   0      4         1
2   2      4         1
3   5      3         1
4   8      3         1
5  10      4         1
6  15      2         0
7  18      2         0
8  19      0         0
```